# How to get rid of the absolute value in ComplexPlot3D[]?

Tags: complex

I'm starting to study complex analysis,so I'm trying out Mathematica as tool for visualizing complex functions. I'm trying to graph $f(z)=z^2 + 1$ with the code:

```
ComplexPlot3D[z^2 + 1 , {z, 2}]
```

and what I get is this:

[image]

Something is wrong, because I expected negative real values of f(z) along the imaginary input axis. So I looked for a description of the function `ComplexPlot3D[]` and it says:

```
ComplexPlot3D[f,{z,Subscript[z, min],Subscript[z, max]}]
```

generates a 3D plot of `Abs[f]` colored by `Arg[f]` over the complex rectangle with corners `Subscript[z, min]` and `Subscript[z, max]`.

So the problem is that this plot function evaluates the absolute value (Abs[f]) instead of the actual value of the funtion it is plotting. Do any of you know how to fix this, or can point me to another function instead of this one? Thanks!

Comment: Would this suit better your purpose? `ComplexPlot[(z^2 + 1), {z, 2}, ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbsArg"]`

Comment: a complex function f[z] in fact have two variables and two values, so we need to use four variables to express such f. That is why we always write f[z] as {u[x,y],v[x,y]}. It is recommend to use ParametricPlot.

Comment: Technically, your plot *does* indicate which values are real and negative — they're those points with $\arg f(z)  = \pi$, which shows up as the points in cyan on the surface.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
  ComplexPlot3D[z^2 + 1, {z, 2}, ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbsArg"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can plot the real and imaginary parts of the function separately using `Plot3D` and `ReIm`:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ReIm[f[x + I y]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

This is a bit confusing on its own, to be honest, but if you look at it you can convince yourself that the points along the imaginary axis (with $|\Im(z)| > 1$) have $\Re(f(z)) < 0$ and $\Im(f(z)) = 0$.

Alternately, replacing `ReIm` with `Re` or `Im` will plot the real or imaginary parts of the function alone, which might make the above properties clearer.